# Error while building Shadowsocks android gituhub code

Tags: linux, kotlin, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, java-native-interface

I am trying to use https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android

To run it, I am following all instructions

Have installed :

```
JDK 1.8
Go 1.11+
Android SDK
Android NDK r16+
```

And to set path, I am doing like this in my system's .profile file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_181
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH

export GOROOT=/home/optimumanddev2/Downloads/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin

export ANDROID_HOME=/home/optimumanddev2/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/tools:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle
```

After that, I have downloaded latest code from github and trying to build it, but it gives these errors:

```
External Native Build Issues=======================>
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/optimumanddev2/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/core/src/main/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/core/src/main/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=/home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
rm -f /home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/lib/armeabi-v7a/*
rm -f /home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
rm -f /home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
mkdir -p /home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/jni-helper
echo [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "jni-helper <= jni-helper.cpp"
/home/optimumanddev2/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -MMD -MP -MF 
/home/optimumanddev2/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar crsD  /home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libcpufeatures.a /home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cpufeatures/cpu-features.o
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/core/src/main/jni/libancillary/fd_recv.c', needed by `/home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ancillary/libancillary/fd_recv.o'.  Stop.
Build command failed.
```

Please help, I am thinking PATH set process could be wrong.

Here is my Application.mk file:

```
APP_ABI                 := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86
APP_PLATFORM            := android-21
APP_STL                 := c++_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION   := clang
```

Here is Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
ROOT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

BUILD_SHARED_EXECUTABLE := $(LOCAL_PATH)/build-shared-executable.mk

########################################################
## libsodium
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

SODIUM_SOURCE := \
    crypto_aead/chacha20poly1305/sodium/aead_chacha20poly1305.c \
    crypto_aead/xchacha20poly1305/sodium/aead_xchacha20poly1305.c \
    crypto_core/curve25519/ref10/curve25519_ref10.c \
    crypto_core/hchacha20/core_hchacha20.c \
    crypto_core/salsa/ref/core_salsa_ref.c \
    crypto_generichash/blake2b/ref/blake2b-compress-ref.c \
    crypto_generichash/blake2b/ref/blake2b-ref.c \
    crypto_generichash/blake2b/ref/generichash_blake2b.c \
    crypto_onetimeauth/poly1305/onetimeauth_poly1305.c \
    crypto_onetimeauth/poly1305/donna/poly1305_donna.c \
    crypto_pwhash/crypto_pwhash.c \
    crypto_pwhash/argon2/argon2-core.c \
    crypto_pwhash/argon2/argon2.c \
    crypto_pwhash/argon2/argon2-encoding.c \
    crypto_pwhash/argon2/argon2-fill-block-ref.c \
    crypto_pwhash/argon2/blake2b-long.c \
    crypto_pwhash/argon2/pwhash_argon2i.c \
    crypto_scalarmult/curve25519/scalarmult_curve25519.c \
    crypto_scalarmult/curve25519/ref10/x25519_ref10.c \
    crypto_stream/chacha20/stream_chacha20.c \
    crypto_stream/chacha20/ref/chacha20_ref.c \
    crypto_stream/salsa20/stream_salsa20.c \
    crypto_stream/salsa20/ref/salsa20_ref.c \
    crypto_verify/sodium/verify.c \
    randombytes/randombytes.c \
    randombytes/sysrandom/randombytes_sysrandom.c \
    sodium/core.c \
    sodium/runtime.c \
    sodium/utils.c \
    sodium/version.c

LOCAL_MODULE := sodium
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libsodium/src/libsodium/include \
                -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
                -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/sodium \
                -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libsodium/src/libsodium/include/sodium \
                -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"libsodium\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"libsodium\" \
                -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0.15\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"libsodium-1.0.15\" \
                -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues\" \
                -DPACKAGE_URL=\"https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium\" \
                -DPACKAGE=\"libsodium\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.15\" \
                -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1                  \
                -DSTDC_HEADERS=1                  \
                -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1              \
                -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1               \
                -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1                 \
                -DHAVE_STRING_H=1                 \
                -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1                 \
                -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1                \
                -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1               \
                -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1                 \
                -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1                 \
                -D__EXTENSIONS__=1                \
                -D_ALL_SOURCE=1                   \
                -D_GNU_SOURCE=1                   \
                -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1      \
                -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1                \
                -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1                  \
                -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\"            \
                -DHAVE_SYS_MMAN_H=1               \
                -DNATIVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1          \
                -DASM_HIDE_SYMBOL=.hidden         \
                -DHAVE_WEAK_SYMBOLS=1             \
                -DHAVE_ATOMIC_OPS=1               \
                -DHAVE_ARC4RANDOM=1               \
                -DHAVE_ARC4RANDOM_BUF=1           \
                -DHAVE_MMAP=1                     \
                -DHAVE_MLOCK=1                    \
                -DHAVE_MADVISE=1                  \
                -DHAVE_MPROTECT=1                 \
                -DHAVE_NANOSLEEP=1                \
                -DHAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN=1           \
                -DHAVE_GETPID=1                   \
                -DCONFIGURED=1

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix libsodium/src/libsodium/,$(SODIUM_SOURCE))

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

########################################################
## libevent
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LIBEVENT_SOURCES := \
    buffer.c bufferevent.c event.c \
    bufferevent_sock.c bufferevent_ratelim.c \
    evthread.c log.c evutil.c evutil_time.c evmap.c epoll.c poll.c signal.c select.c

LOCAL_MODULE := event
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix libevent/, $(LIBEVENT_SOURCES))
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libevent \
    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libevent/include \

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

########################################################
## libancillary
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

ANCILLARY_SOURCE := fd_recv.c fd_send.c

LOCAL_MODULE := libancillary
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libancillary

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix libancillary/, $(ANCILLARY_SOURCE))

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

########################################################
## libbloom
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

BLOOM_SOURCE := bloom.c murmur2/MurmurHash2.c

LOCAL_MODULE := libbloom
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libbloom \
                -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libbloom/murmur2

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix shadowsocks-libev/libbloom/, $(BLOOM_SOURCE))

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

########################################################
## libipset
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

bdd_src = bdd/assignments.c bdd/basics.c bdd/bdd-iterator.c bdd/expanded.c \
                  bdd/reachable.c bdd/read.c bdd/write.c
map_src = map/allocation.c map/inspection.c map/ipv4_map.c map/ipv6_map.c \
                  map/storage.c
set_src = set/allocation.c set/inspection.c set/ipv4_set.c set/ipv6_set.c \
                  set/iterator.c set/storage.c

IPSET_SOURCE := general.c $(bdd_src) $(map_src) $(set_src)

LOCAL_MODULE := libipset
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libipset/include \
                -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libcork/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix shadowsocks-libev/libipset/src/libipset/,$(IPSET_SOURCE))

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

########################################################
## libcork
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

cli_src := cli/commands.c
core_src := core/allocator.c core/error.c core/gc.c \
            core/hash.c core/ip-address.c core/mempool.c \
            core/timestamp.c core/u128.c
ds_src := ds/array.c ds/bitset.c ds/buffer.c ds/dllist.c \
          ds/file-stream.c ds/hash-table.c ds/managed-buffer.c \
          ds/ring-buffer.c ds/slice.c
posix_src := posix/directory-walker.c posix/env.c posix/exec.c \
             posix/files.c posix/process.c posix/subprocess.c
pthreads_src := pthreads/thread.c

CORK_SOURCE := $(cli_src) $(core_src) $(ds_src) $(posix_src) $(pthreads_src)

LOCAL_MODULE := libcork
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libcork/include \
                -DCORK_API=CORK_LOCAL

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix shadowsocks-libev/libcork/src/libcork/,$(CORK_SOURCE))

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

########################################################
## libev
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libev
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG -DHAVE_CONFIG_H \
                -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/libev
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    libev/ev.c \
    libev/event.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

########################################################
## redsocks
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

REDSOCKS_SOURCES := base.c http-connect.c \
    log.c md5.c socks5.c \
    base64.c http-auth.c http-relay.c main.c \
    parser.c redsocks.c socks4.c utils.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libevent

LOCAL_MODULE := redsocks
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix redsocks/, $(REDSOCKS_SOURCES)) 
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=gnu99 -DUSE_IPTABLES \
    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/redsocks \
    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libevent/include \
    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libevent

include $(BUILD_SHARED_EXECUTABLE)

########################################################
## shadowsocks-libev local
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

SHADOWSOCKS_SOURCES := local.c \
    cache.c udprelay.c utils.c netutils.c json.c jconf.c \
    acl.c http.c tls.c rule.c \
    crypto.c aead.c stream.c base64.c \
    plugin.c ppbloom.c \
    android.c

LOCAL_MODULE    := ss-local
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix shadowsocks-libev/src/, $(SHADOWSOCKS_SOURCES))
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -DMODULE_LOCAL \
                    -DUSE_CRYPTO_MBEDTLS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H \
                    -DCONNECT_IN_PROGRESS=EINPROGRESS \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/shadowsocks-libev \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libancillary \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/mbedtls/include  \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/pcre \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libsodium/src/libsodium/include \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libsodium/src/libsodium/include/sodium \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libcork/include \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libipset/include \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libbloom \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libev

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libev libmbedtls libipset libcork libbloom \
    libsodium libancillary libpcre

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_EXECUTABLE)

########################################################
## shadowsocks-libev tunnel
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

SHADOWSOCKS_SOURCES := tunnel.c \
    cache.c udprelay.c utils.c netutils.c json.c jconf.c \
    crypto.c aead.c stream.c base64.c \
    plugin.c ppbloom.c \
    android.c

LOCAL_MODULE    := ss-tunnel
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix shadowsocks-libev/src/, $(SHADOWSOCKS_SOURCES))
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -DMODULE_TUNNEL \
                    -DUSE_CRYPTO_MBEDTLS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSSTUNNEL_JNI \
                    -DCONNECT_IN_PROGRESS=EINPROGRESS \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libancillary \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libsodium/src/libsodium/include \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libsodium/src/libsodium/include/sodium \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/mbedtls/include \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libev \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libcork/include \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/shadowsocks-libev/libbloom \
                    -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/shadowsocks-libev

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libev libmbedtls libsodium libcork libbloom libancillary

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_EXECUTABLE)

########################################################
## jni-helper
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE:= jni-helper

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++11

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/libancillary

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= jni-helper.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -llog

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures libancillary

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

########################################################
## tun2socks
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=gnu99
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DBADVPN_THREADWORK_USE_PTHREAD -DBADVPN_LINUX -DBADVPN_BREACTOR_BADVPN -D_GNU_SOURCE
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DBADVPN_USE_SIGNALFD -DBADVPN_USE_EPOLL
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DBADVPN_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DBADVPN_THREAD_SAFE
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG -DANDROID
# LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DTUN2SOCKS_JNI

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libancillary

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/libancillary \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/badvpn/lwip/src/include/ipv4 \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/badvpn/lwip/src/include/ipv6 \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/badvpn/lwip/src/include \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/badvpn/lwip/custom \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/badvpn/

TUN2SOCKS_SOURCES := \
        base/BLog_syslog.c \
        system/BReactor_badvpn.c \
        system/BSignal.c \
        system/BConnection_common.c \
        system/BConnection_unix.c \
        system/BTime.c \
        system/BUnixSignal.c \
        system/BNetwork.c \
        flow/StreamRecvInterface.c \
        flow/PacketRecvInterface.c \
        flow/PacketPassInterface.c \
        flow/StreamPassInterface.c \
        flow/SinglePacketBuffer.c \
        flow/BufferWriter.c \
        flow/PacketBuffer.c \
        flow/PacketStreamSender.c \
        flow/PacketPassConnector.c \
        flow/PacketProtoFlow.c \
        flow/PacketPassFairQueue.c \
        flow/PacketProtoEncoder.c \
        flow/PacketProtoDecoder.c \
        socksclient/BSocksClient.c \
        tuntap/BTap.c \
        lwip/src/core/timers.c \
        lwip/src/core/udp.c \
        lwip/src/core/memp.c \
        lwip/src/core/init.c \
        lwip/src/core/pbuf.c \
        lwip/src/core/tcp.c \
        lwip/src/core/tcp_out.c \
        lwip/src/core/netif.c \
        lwip/src/core/def.c \
        lwip/src/core/mem.c \
        lwip/src/core/tcp_in.c \
        lwip/src/core/stats.c \
        lwip/src/core/inet_chksum.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv4/icmp.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv4/igmp.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv4/ip4_addr.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv4/ip_frag.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv4/ip4.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv4/autoip.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv6/ethip6.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv6/inet6.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv6/ip6_addr.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv6/mld6.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv6/dhcp6.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv6/icmp6.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv6/ip6.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv6/ip6_frag.c \
        lwip/src/core/ipv6/nd6.c \
        lwip/custom/sys.c \
        tun2socks/tun2socks.c \
        base/DebugObject.c \
        base/BLog.c \
        base/BPending.c \
        system/BDatagram_unix.c \
        flowextra/PacketPassInactivityMonitor.c \
        tun2socks/SocksUdpGwClient.c \
        udpgw_client/UdpGwClient.c

LOCAL_MODULE := tun2socks

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -llog

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix badvpn/, $(TUN2SOCKS_SOURCES))

include $(BUILD_SHARED_EXECUTABLE)

########################################################
## mbed TLS
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := mbedtls

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/mbedtls/include

MBEDTLS_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/mbedtls/library/*.c)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MBEDTLS_SOURCES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

########################################################
## pcre
########################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := pcre

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/pcre/dist $(LOCAL_PATH)/pcre

libpcre_src_files := \
    dist/pcre_byte_order.c \
    dist/pcre_compile.c \
    dist/pcre_config.c \
    dist/pcre_dfa_exec.c \
    dist/pcre_exec.c \
    dist/pcre_fullinfo.c \
    dist/pcre_get.c \
    dist/pcre_globals.c \
    dist/pcre_jit_compile.c \
    dist/pcre_maketables.c \
    dist/pcre_newline.c \
    dist/pcre_ord2utf8.c \
    dist/pcre_refcount.c \
    dist/pcre_string_utils.c \
    dist/pcre_study.c \
    dist/pcre_tables.c \
    dist/pcre_ucd.c \
    dist/pcre_valid_utf8.c \
    dist/pcre_version.c \
    dist/pcre_xclass.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix pcre/, $(libpcre_src_files)) $(LOCAL_PATH)/patch/pcre/pcre_chartables.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# Import cpufeatures
$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
```

In my project the files that are missing: 
for eg.( core/.externalNativeBuild/ndkBuild/debug/armeabi-v7a) these folder are empty. I think it can be the problem.
Because In my other NDK project, these folder have files and some code

Comment: Here is what make is complaing about: *"No rule to make target '/home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/core/src/main/jni/libancillary/fd_recv.c', needed by '/home/optimumanddev2/Pictures/flag/shadowsocks-android-master/plugin/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ancillary/libancillary/fd_recv.o'."*

Comment: @jww  I just added Application.mk file, please check

Comment: My bad, I meant `Android.mk`; not `Applcation.mk`. (The one with `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)` is the one folks probably need to see).

Comment: Also, be sure to read [C++ Library Support](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support) in the Android NDK docs. If the LLVM runtime is being used by two or more native components in your app, then you can't use static. That is, you have to change `APP_STL := c++_static` to `APP_STL := c++_shared`. You also have to use the same runtime for _all_ components; runtimes cannot be mixed/matched.

Answer (score 0):

This error was solved after I cloned project properly by git command as given on https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android.git

So, to remove NDK error, you need to install and set path of all required things, and clone properly, so that all subfolders can be cloned properly, the errors was causing due to files not available.

But I am getting other errors like libraries conflict: 
Error "Program type already present" android.support.customtabs